# How to check if a list exist inside another list

Tags: node.js

So I have a list `a` that contain the string `"ab"` and another list `b` that contain a list that contain the string `"ab"`. So it look something like this:

```
var a = ["ab"]
var b = [["ab"]]
```

How can I check if `a` is in `b`. I have try using `b.includes(a)` that result in a `false` and I also have try `b.indexOf(a)` which also return `false`. The way that I currently use is this:

```
var flag = false
var a = ["ab"]
var b = [["ab"]]

b.forEach((i) => {
    if (i.join("") == a.join("")) flag = true
})
console.log(flag)
```

Is there like a shorter way?

Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little trick for you. You can compare two array if you use `toString()` method.

```js
const a = ["ab"];
const b = [["ab"]];
const result = b.some(p => p.toString().includes(a));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quiet sure what exactly you want to check but here are 2 examples:

```js
var a = ["ab"];
var b = [["ab"]];
var flag = false;

//Example 1: search for "ab" in the nested array
b.forEach(el=>{
el.forEach(innerEl=>{
  if(innerEl === "ab") flag = true;
});
});

console.log(`Result 1 ${flag}`);

//Example 1: seach for the exact array ["ab"]
b.forEach(el=>{
 if(el == a)flag = true;
});

console.log(`Result 2 ${flag}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have references you can do as follows:

```
var a = ["ab"];
var b = [a];
b.includes(a); // true
```

Otherwise you need to convert those arrays to strings and compare those as others suggested or compare inside values of those nested arrays one by one because:

```
['a'] != ['a'] // this is true because those are 2 different arrays
```